# How to forward a Remote Port to a Local Port in a NodeJS App

Tags: node.js, ssh, port

I am creating a node app which Maps a Local Port to a port on a Remote machine, via SSH.

In shell command I can do :

```
ssh -fN -l username -i ~/.ssh/myKey.pem  -L 9999:localhost:27017  1.2.3.4
```

which opens a persistent ssh connection to 1.2.3.4 and maps 27017 port on the Remote to 9999 on my Local.

But how can I get this -L action to happen in nodejs 
I am using the npm ssh2 package to perform the ssh connection.

Comment: Check this one https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel, I think it's exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: Do you want to forward local to remote, or remote to local? You question and your title don't match.

Comment: I'm using mongodump on my local shell to create a local dump of the remote database

Comment: No - localtunnell is not the right solution.  I am not looking to expose my localhost !.  I would like to map a remote local port to a port on my local machine

Comment: the ssh command does exactly what I want it to - i just want to find  a way in Node to do the same thing

Answer (score 3):

You can use the example below to do that reverse ssh tunneling. I assume the remote host uses public and private key authentication in the example, if this not the case please change the example accordingly. Not to forget you have to listen on local port to which you are forwarding the requests.

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var Connection = require('ssh2');
var net = require('net')
var c
var username = 'username'
var hostname = 'remote host IP or domain name'
var port = 22
var privKey = path.join(__dirname, 'path to private key', 'filename')
var localAddr = 'localhost'
var localPort = 'local port on which you want to receive the requests'
var remotePort = 'remote port that you want to forward'
var remoteAddr = '0.0.0.0'

c = new Connection()
c.on('connect', function() {
 console.log('Connection :: connect')
})

c.on('tcp connection', function(info, accept, reject) {
  console.log('TCP :: INCOMING CONNECTION: ' + 
  require('util').inspect(info));

  var stream = accept()
  var socket


  stream.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('TCP :: DATA: ' + data);
  })

  stream.on('end', function() {
   console.log('TCP :: EOF');
  })

  stream.on('error', function(err) {
   console.log('TCP :: ERROR: ' + err);
  })

  stream.on('close', function(had_err) {
    console.log('TCP :: CLOSED', had_err ? 'had error' : '');
  })

  stream.pause()
  socket = net.connect(localPort, localAddr, function () {
    stream.pipe(socket);
    socket.pipe(stream);
    stream.resume();
  })
})

c.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('Connection :: ready')
  c.forwardIn(remoteAddr, remotePort, function(err) {
    if (err) { throw err }
    console.log('Forwarding connections from remote server on port 7070 to 
      node socket!');
  })
})

 c.on('error', function(err) {
   console.log('Connection :: error :: ', err)
 })

  c.on('end', function() {
    console.log('Connection :: end')
  })

  c.on('close', function(had_error) {
    console.log('Connection :: close', had_error ? 'had error' : '')
  })

 var obj = {
  host: hostname,
  port: port,
  username: username,
  privateKey: fs.readFileSync(privKey).toString()
 }

 c.connect(obj)
```

Comment: That's not really the same ; it works for 1:1 port bindings, but it fails if we try to add 2 forwardIn on same distant port (it works with ssh -R)

Comment: I could not find an example using ssh2 where you forwardIn AND proxy the traffic to the destination. Thank you!